Accessing values in a dictionary of data from a sports
I'm trying to take NHL player statistics from an API and I'm having difficulty accessing the values of the dictionary to pull specific metrics. I am able to load the API properly and access the gamelog but cannot find a way to extract the values from the gamelog.
Here is what the dictionary looks like:
"gameLog": [
        {
            "gameId": 2023021306,
            "teamAbbrev": "EDM",
            "homeRoadFlag": "R",
            "gameDate": "2024-04-17",
            "goals": 0,
            "assists": 0,
            "commonName": {
                "default": "Oilers"
            },
            "opponentCommonName": {
                "default": "Coyotes"
            },
            "points": 0,
            "plusMinus": -2,
            "powerPlayGoals": 0,
            "powerPlayPoints": 0,
            "gameWinningGoals": 0,
            "otGoals": 0,
            "shots": 2,
            "shifts": 20,
            "shorthandedGoals": 0,
            "shorthandedPoints": 0,
            "pim": 0,
            "toi": "17:44",
            "opponentAbbrev": "ARI"
        },

With multiple keys like this for each game played. I am trying to access specific metrics like 'goals', 'points', etc. sum them up and divide them to get averages.
I have tried:
for key in player_data_json['gameLog']:
    goals = 0
    for val in key:
        if key == 'goals':
            goals += key[val]
    print(goals)

But returns zeroes every time.

for game in player_data_json['gameLog']: print(game['goals'])…?

According to your sample data, player_data_json['gameLog'] is a list of dictionaries.  So in your loop for key in player_data_json['gameLog'], key is an entire dictionary.  So if key == 'goals' is never true.

@deceze Thank you! I was confused with the entries being values as opposed to entire dictionaries as another user pointed out. Thank you both.

I assume your player_data_json looks like a dictionary where the key is gamelog that contains a list of the dictionary, this is how you can calculate the analytics, I have used sample data from your given player_data_json to show you the example approach.
import json
player_data_json = {
    "gameLog": [
        {
            "gameId": 2023021306,
            "teamAbbrev": "EDM",
            "homeRoadFlag": "R",
            "gameDate": "2024-04-17",
            "goals": 0,
            "assists": 0,
            "commonName": {
                "default": "Oilers"
            },
            "opponentCommonName": {
                "default": "Coyotes"
            },
            "points": 0,
            "plusMinus": -2,
            "powerPlayGoals": 0,
            "powerPlayPoints": 0,
            "gameWinningGoals": 0,
            "otGoals": 0,
            "shots": 2,
            "shifts": 20,
            "shorthandedGoals": 0,
            "shorthandedPoints": 0,
            "pim": 0,
            "toi": "17:44",
            "opponentAbbrev": "ARI"
        },
        {
            "gameId": 2023021309,
            "teamAbbrev": "EDM",
            "homeRoadFlag": "R",
            "gameDate": "2024-04-17",
            "goals": 1,
            "assists": 0,
            "commonName": {
                "default": "Oilers"
            },
            "opponentCommonName": {
                "default": "Coyotes"
            },
            "points": 0,
            "plusMinus": -2,
            "powerPlayGoals": 0,
            "powerPlayPoints": 0,
            "gameWinningGoals": 0,
            "otGoals": 0,
            "shots": 2,
            "shifts": 20,
            "shorthandedGoals": 0,
            "shorthandedPoints": 0,
            "pim": 0,
            "toi": "17:44",
            "opponentAbbrev": "ARI"
        }
    ]    
}
player_data = player_data_json['gameLog']

total_goals = 0
total_assists = 0
total_points = 0
total_shots = 0
total_pim = 0


for game in player_data:
    total_goals += game.get('goals', 0)
    total_assists += game.get('assists', 0)
    total_points += game.get('points', 0)
    total_shots += game.get('shots', 0)
    total_pim += game.get('pim', 0)

num_games = len(player_data)
avg_goals = total_goals / num_games
avg_assists = total_assists / num_games
avg_points = total_points / num_games
avg_shots = total_shots / num_games
avg_pim = total_pim / num_games

print(f"Average Goals: {avg_goals:.2f}")
print(f"Average Assists: {avg_assists:.2f}")
print(f"Average Points: {avg_points:.2f}")
print(f"Average Shots: {avg_shots:.2f}")
print(f"Average PIM: {avg_pim:.2f}")

Output:
Average Goals: 0.50
Average Assists: 0.00
Average Points: 0.00
Average Shots: 2.00
Average PIM: 0.00


Why not convert to a dataframe and let pandas do the stats?
df = pd.DataFrame(player_data_json['gameLog'])

# Calculate totals and averages
totals = df[['goals', 'assists', 'points', 'shots', 'pim']].sum()
averages = df[['goals', 'assists', 'points', 'shots', 'pim']].mean()

Output:
print(totals)
goals      1
assists    0
points     0
shots      4
pim        0
dtype: int64

print(averages)
goals      0.5
assists    0.0
points     0.0
shots      2.0
pim        0.0
dtype: float64

